# React.js, I can't pass a state from a parent component to a child component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate, children

I have a react app that consists of a Layout component and everything else is wrapped in this layout.

I have an App.tsx file and the return part of the code looks like this:

```
return (
  <Layout>
    <div className='App'>
      {isConnected ? <SignedInHero /> : <NotSignedInHero />}
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
  </Layout>
)
```

I'm trying to pass a state from the `Layout` component to the `NotSignedInHero` component.  The return part of the Layout code looks like this:

```
return (
    <div>
        {isValid ? null : <Placeholder />}
        {isValid ? <Navbar /> : null}
        {isValid ? children : null}
    </div>
)
```

So if I had a useState variable like `const [passed, setPassed] = useState('pass this'):` How would I send it from `Layout` to `NotSignedInHero`?

Comment: I would suggest keeping your layout as just a layout and not putting any logic into it that isn't layout related. Run the whole thing with another parent component that does the logic.

Comment: I would suggest reading and understanding the core concepts of react. https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to pass down props to child components. It depends a lot on the type and size of the project and which solutions to choose.

The simplest solution is passing the prop down to child components using a render function. I personally don't like this as much, but it does the trick without needing dependencies or creating a global state/context.

**Layout.jsx**

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const [passed, setPassed] = useState('pass this') ;

  return (
    <div>
        {isValid ? null : <Placeholder />}
        {isValid ? <Navbar /> : null}
        {isValid ? children({ passed }) : null} // <-- note that the `children` prop is a function
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
return (
  <Layout>
    {({ passed }) => (
      <div className='App'>
        {isConnected ? <SignedInHero /> : <NotSignedInHero passed={passed} />}
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
    )}
  </Layout>
)
```

The second option is to use [React Context](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext), which enables having a global state without needing to do "prop drilling".

The third option is to use a global state management tool like [Zustand](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand).

Comment: This gives me `Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.` and it won't load `NotSignedInHero`. I think `{({ passed }) => (` is causing the problem.

Comment: I ended up using `useContext` to fix my propblem. You suggested context so if you alter you're answer to explain how I did it, I'll accept it. I used this https://gist.github.com/ChristianOConnor/c22e36dda9ee79a7728ee531002728ce and this https://gist.github.com/ChristianOConnor/78c97359434e0a8e446081a064608a91, which allowed me to do `const state = useContext(EmailContext);` in any component to access `state.email` and `state.setEmail`

Comment: Not sure why your code fails. Did you make both changes, as seen in the example code? Here you can see it in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-night-bh0bro

Answer (score 1):

you can pass it as a props in `Layout`:

```
const [passed, setPassed] = useState('pass this');
return (
  <Layout>
    <div className='App'>
      {isConnected ? <SignedInHero /> : <NotSignedInHero passed={passed} />}
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
  </Layout>
)
```

and in `NotSignedInHero`:

```
const NotSignedInHero = ({passed}) => {
  console.log(passed);
  return (
    <div>
        {isValid ? null : <Placeholder />}
        {isValid ? <Navbar /> : null}
        {isValid ? children : null}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: The code you posted for `Layout` is meant to be `App` right? And the code you posted for `NotSignedInHero` is meant to be `Layout` right?

Comment: Yes I fixed the code, there were a mistake. 
The first block of code is `App` and the second one is `NotSignedInHero`. The `passed` is set in `App` and send to `NotSignedInHero`.

Answer (score 1):

You pass it as a property. So

```
return (
  <Layout>
    <div className='App'>
      {isConnected ? <SignedInHero /> : <NotSignedInHero passed={passed} />}
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
  </Layout>
)
```

and in NotSignedInHero:

```
const NotSignedInHero = (props) => {
 const {passed} = props
}
```

**Edit**: I think I understand after your comment. The passed variable is changed in the Layout component, and you need to pass it first up to the App component and then down to NotSignedInHero. If the variable is changed in a function inside Layout, you can do it like this:

```
const Layout = (props) => {
  const { updateParent } = props
  
  function updatePassed(){
    setPassed('pass this')
    updateParent('pass this')
  }
}
```

Then is the App component you do this:

```
const [passed, setPassed] = useState('')

function updatePassed(newValue){
  setPassed(newValue)
}

return (
  <Layout updateParent={updatePassed}>
    <div className='App'>
      {isConnected ? <SignedInHero /> : <NotSignedInHero passed={passed} />}
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
  </Layout>
)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to get `passed` out of Layout. Setting the state in one component doesn't seem to pass it to wrapped components.

Answer (score 0):

```
<>{isValid ? React.cloneElement(children, { passed }) : null}</>
```

You can pass props to children by using cloneElement().

See more: https://react.dev/reference/react/cloneElement